# Writing/discussions about the aesthetics of code?

Tags: code-quality, source-code

I'm looking for considerations of the questions "Can code be beautiful?" and "What makes code beautiful?"

Examples would include:

- This academic paper: [Obfuscation, Weird Languages, and Code Aesthetics](http://www.obfuscators.org/2008/04/obfuscation-weird-languages-and-code.html)
- This blog post: [Hamon or the Skin Deep Beauty of Code](http://www.deadprogrammer.com/hamon-or-the-skin-deep-beauty-of-code)

Please note that I'm not trying to start a discussion here, or asking for opinions about what makes code beautiful, or for code you think is beautiful; I'm trying to find stuff that has already been published.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the book "Beautiful Code" By Oram and Wilson. (Published by O'Reilly). Its a good read, 20 or so essays by different folks on well what you would expect.

Comment: I agree. The chapter "Beautiful concurrency" in Haskell is freely available: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/beautiful.pdf (the site is down as we speak)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I have read that one yet. (And my copy of the book is sitting right on the shelf next to me) And from everything I have heard Simon Payton-Jones is an excellent writer/speaker.

Answer (score 1):

[Literate Programming site](http://www.literateprogramming.com/) provides many articles on the approach described by its inventor as follows:

> I believe that the time is ripe for significantly better documentation of programs, and that we can best achieve this by considering programs to be works of literature. Hence, my title: "Literate Programming."
>
> Let us change our traditional attitude to the construction of programs: Instead of imagining that our main task is to instruct a computer what to do, let us concentrate rather on explaining to human beings what we want a computer to do.
>
> *The practitioner of literate programming can be regarded as an essayist, whose main concern is with exposition and excellence of style*. Such an author, with thesaurus in hand, chooses the names of variables carefully and explains what each variable means. He or she strives for a program that is comprehensible because its concepts have been introduced in an order that is best for human understanding, using a mixture of formal and informal methods that reinforce each other.
>
> *(Donald Knuth. "Literate Programming (1984)" in Literate Programming. CSLI, 1992, pg. 99.)*